# Error de instalación CPanel en Centos 7

Tags: servidor, cpanel, centos7

Necesito de su ayuda.

He intentado instalar CPanel en Centos 7, pero me muestra error al final y por ende no se abre en el navegador. ¿Alguien tiene alguna solución para esto?

Se los agradecería infinitamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Leyendo leyendo en el sitio de cpanel, encontré esto: https://docs.cpanel.net/installation-guide/system-requirements/ Quizás te sea de utilidad. Por cierto, a CentOS ya lo enterraron: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS Saludos.

Comment: @fredyfx  Es lo que estaba revisando, pensé que le darían mate hasta enero del próximo año. Igual gracias por el dato. Saludos.